# Expression Must have a Class type (operator)

Tags: c++

I have an operator which receives the address of an unmodifiable character string. I'm trying to compare the size of the received address to the Items sku. If they are the same I return true, if not false. I'm getting an error on c.size() that says the expression must have a class type and I'm not sure why

```
char Item::operator==(const char* c)
{
    if (this->get_sku.size() == c.size()) //Error
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

//getter function

```
char Item::get_sku() const
{
    return *m_sku;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that pointers have a size() member function? And why are you working with character pointers at all?

Comment: Teacher specified that I must used char pointers

Comment: Get a better teacher. If you need to find the length of a C-style string pointed to by a character pointer, use strlen(), but that woon't work as an equality operation - "foo" and "bar" have the same length but are not equal.

Comment: Well my uni doesn't let me choose my teacher so..

Comment: "Well my uni doesn't let me choose my teacher so."  - Actually, it probably does if you and other students complain about him enough. Advice from ex university lecturer.

Comment: `c.size()` ... did you mean `std::strlen(c)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.  But since `get_sku` returns a single `char` it makes not an awful lot of sense to query its length or compare it to a `char*` in any way.  The following compiles but I'm not sure what your exact problem is.

```
class Item
{
public:
  bool operator==(char c) const;
  char get_sku() const;
private:
  char * m_sku;
};

bool Item::operator==(char c) const
{
  return this->get_sku() == c;
}

char Item::get_sku() const
{
  return *m_sku;
}
```